# Bootstrap have no gutter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can I use bootstrap grid with no gutter? I want 3 columns with one row http://prntscr.com/6gpmhm 
I had posted the markup about css I am using default css of framework

```html
<section class="team-block">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <img src="images/photo-01.jpg" height="534" width="534" alt="image description">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <img src="images/photo-02.jpg" height="267" width="266" alt="image description">
   <img src="images/photo-10.jpg" height="267" width="266" alt="image description">
   <img src="images/photo-03.jpg" height="267" width="266" alt="image description">
   <img src="images/photo-04.jpg" height="267" width="266" alt="image description">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <img src="images/photo-05.jpg" height="534" width="534" alt="image description">
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can give more details abouts img css ? And the size of your container ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use external class for it.

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the images to stack on one column, you need to remove px widths and re-define rows like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="images/photo-02.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image description">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="images/photo-10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image description">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="images/photo-03.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image description">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="images/photo-04.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image description">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can add this to your css to remove the gutter:

```
.col-sm-4    {
    padding: 0px;
}
.col-sm-6    {
    padding: 0px;
}
```